# UIAlertView open when UIWebView loads for more than a specific time

Tags: uiwebview, loading, nstimer, uialertview

I'm trying to alert the user if a web view loads for more than 10 seconds.  The error is incase there is slow or no internet connection.  The problem is that this code does not work.

In the first case I'm attempting to start the timer when the web view starts loading.  Then either expire with doing nothing or display an alert after 10 seconds that the web view is loading very slow or not at all.

In the second case I've attempted to start the timer when the web view starts and either show the alert after 10 seconds or invalidate the timer before it expires.

Neither of which seem to work correctly.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(webViewLoading) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

webViewLoadTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(showAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

[super viewDidLoad];
[self configureView];
}

-(void)showAlert
{
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                      message: @""
                      delegate: self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
if (self.bgWebView.loading){[alert show];}    
}
```

I have tried putting the timer in the following method, but then it alerts every time regardless of whether the device is connected to internet or not.  It doesn't seem to invalidate.

```
-(void)webViewLoading
{
  if (self.bgView.loading) 
  {
    [self.avBackGround startAnimating];
     webViewLoadTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(showAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
  }
  else
  {
    [self.avBackGround stopAnimating];
    [webViewLoadTimer invalidate];
  }

  if (self.icnWebView.loading) 
  {
    [self.avIcon startAnimating];
  }
  else 
  {
    [self.avIcon stopAnimating];
  }
}
```

I apologize if I have missed a post on this.  I just can't seem to put this together.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: 1. Don't poll the web view for its loading property — implement the appropriate delegate methods, instead! 2. 10 seconds is **MUCH** too short a timeout, especially if you plan on shoving a UIAlertView in ones face. That's just rude.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I went back and used the reachability(?) class from apple to check for internet connectivity.  It made for a much more reliable error message!